# How can I use method of which parameter is vector?

Tags: c++, virtual

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Shape{
protected:
    int _r;
    int _w;
    int _h;

public:
    Shape(double r) : _r(r) {}
    Shape(double w, double h) : _w(w), _h(h) {}

    virtual double area(vector<Shape *>){
        cout << "shape:: area " << endl;
        return _r;
    }
};

class Circle : public Shape{

public:
    Circle(double r) : Shape(r) {}
    double area(vector<Shape *>) { return _r*_r*atan(1)*4.0; }
};

class Triangle : public Shape{

public:
    Triangle(double s) : Shape(s) {}
    double area(vector<Shape *>) { return sqrt(3) * pow(_r, 2) / 4; }
};

class Rectangular : public Shape{

public:
    Rectangular(double w, double h) :Shape(w, h) {}
    double area(vector<Shape *>) { return  _w * _h ;}
};

int main()
{

    int n;
    char info;
    int value;
    int value2;
    double sum;
    vector<Shape > collection;
    vector<int> answer;

    sum = 0;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> info;
        if (info == 'C')
        {
            cin >> value;
            Circle c(value);
            collection.push_back(c);
        }
        else if (info == 'R')
        {
            cin >> value;
            cin >> value2;
            Rectangular r(value, value2);
            collection.push_back(r);
        }
        else
        {
            cin >> value;
            Triangle t(value);
            collection.push_back(t);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        sum += collection[i].area(&collection[i]);
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

As you can see , I used an abstract class Shape, and the three concrete class , Circle, Rectangular, Triangle. 
And I wanna sum areas of all shapes. such as 
[image]

First input represents how many shapes we have to calculate. C for circles, R for rectangle, and T for regular triangles.

And I want to override function "area" of which parameter is vector.
But my error is [image]

How can I solve this  no viable conversion from 'std::__1::__vector_base<Shape, std::__1::allocator >::value_type'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Shape{
protected:
    int _r;
    int _w;
    int _h;

public:
    Shape(double r) : _r(r) {}
    Shape(double w, double h) : _w(w), _h(h) {}
    virtual double area(vector<Shape *>) = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape{
public:
    Circle(double r) : Shape(r) {}
    double area(vector<Shape *>) { return _r*_r*atan(1)*4.0; }
};

class Triangle : public Shape{
public:
    Triangle(double s) : Shape(s) {}
    double area(vector<Shape *>) { return sqrt(3) * pow(_r, 2) / 4; }
};

class Rectangle : public Shape{
public:
    Rectangle(double w, double h) :Shape(w, h) {}
    double area(vector<Shape *>) { return  _w * _h ;}
};

int main()
{

    int n;
    char info;
    int value;
    int value2;
    double sum;
    vector<Shape*> collection;
    vector<int> answer;

    sum = 0;

    cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> info;
        if (info == 'C')
        {
            cin >> value;
            Circle c(value);
            collection.push_back(&c);
        }
        else if (info == 'R')
        {
            cin >> value;
            cin >> value2;
            Rectangle r(value, value2);
            collection.push_back(&r);
        }
        else
        {
            cin >> value;
            Triangle t(value);
            collection.push_back(&t);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        sum += collection[i]->area(collection);
    }
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2) << sum << endl;
}
```

I changed and fix!

Comment: `area` is not supposed to take any arguments at all, and the vector is supposed to contain `Shape*`, not `Shape`. Review the introduction to polymorphism in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: `collection` is of type `vector<Shape>`.  You are then taking a single element `collection[i]` which is of type `Shape`, and trying to pass that as a `vector<Shape*>`.  You _could_ construct a vector from that pointer by calling `.area({ &collection[i] })` ...  BUT may I ask why on earth this `area` function receives a `vector<Shape*>` in the first place?  You never use that parameter.  It also makes no sense.  What is it supposed to represent, and why is it there?

Comment: Yes, I put strange type into my function " area" . It 's basic mistake I think....
And my intention is to use vector<shape *> was to make a function "area" which represent sum of all shape's area. so I use vector!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphism does not work with concrete classes!

By declaring `vector<Shape> collection;`, you declare a `vector` of `Shape`, not of `Circle`, `Triangle` or `Rectangular`. You probably want `collection` to be of type `vector<Shape*>` to be able to utilize polymorphism.

Another issue with your code is that you don't pass `collection`, which is of type `vector<Shape>`, but `collection[i]` which just is of type `Shape`.

This would probably also explain your error, since your compiler most likely wants to parse `Shape` into `vector<Shape*>` since that's type of the argument of `area`. This is not possible, and therefore probably causes your compiler error.

Also, if you want to pass just `collection`, you'd have to make sure the types are matching. `vector<Shape>` is not implicitly convertable into `vector<Shape*>`

Comment: THank you for your help. I finally solved

Comment: Glad i could help. If my answer helped you, how about marking it as accepted? ;)